# How to use variables in a <a href> html tag using jinja?

Tags: html, jinja2

Below is a made example of what I am trying to do.  Essentially I am trying to create variables to reduce the amount of clutter and for other reasons.  The link goes to in this case `"use_var"` and not the correct link.  Is there a way to use a variable in the "a href = portion"?

```
{% set ht = 'http:' %}
{% set url_path = '//random_url:' %}
{% set port = '8000' %}
{% set use_var = '{{ ht }} {{ url_path }} {{ port }}' %}
{% set url = '<a href = "{{ use_var }}"> example url </a>' %}

... html code...
    <tr>
      <td> {{ url }} </td
```

If i did:

```
 {% set url = '<a href =" http://random_url:8000"> example </a> %}
```

It'll work that way but I am trying to avoid having to do that for each link.
I've tried the 'join' and it still results with "The requested URL /{{ use_var }} was not found...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

```
{% set use_var = ht + url_path + port %}
{% set url = '<a href = ' + use_var + '> example url </a>' %}
```

this will retrieve the correct path

Answer (score 0):

You Can try in this way:

```
{% set use_var = [ht, url_path , port]|join(',') %}
```

Comment: I phrased the question incorrectly.  It isn't about joining the variables but the when you click on the link, it shows an error with the name of the variable, in this case "use_var"

Comment: Okay! Try to fetch the url on which you are redirected on click, may be quotes are creating problem.